# Obtain a reference to a property in C# and assign this to another property

Tags: c#, reflection

If I have

```
public class ClassA
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> WhateverA { get; set; }
}
```

and also

```
public class ClassB
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> WhateverB { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to obtain a reference to `ClassA.WhateverA` and assign it to `ClassB.WhateverB` such that if `WhateverA` is later assigned a value, `WhateverB` will consequently be assigned the same?

If I was looking to do the same with methods then I could declare `WhateverB` as an `Action` and then assign `WhateverA` as a delegate, thus giving it a kind of 'pass-through' capability. Is it possible to do the same with a property such that `WhataverB` always shows the value of `WhateverA`?

Comment: Does ClassB have a reference to/know about ClassA?

Comment: No, neither know of each other so the assignation will be done via Reflection in a 'neutral location'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to ClassA in ClassB you can simply wrap the ClassA property.

```
public class ClassB
{
    static ClassA a;

    public static IEnumerable<string> WhateverB
    {
        get { return a.WhateverA; }
        set { a.WhateverA = value; }
    }
}
```

If not, you can use Action<> and Func<> to pass around delegates to the getters and setters - similar to what you said you have done with methods. You just have to treat the setter and getters as separate methods (underneath they are).

To do this with a setter:
    public class ClassB
    {
        static Action> aSetter;
        static Func> aGetter;

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> WhateverB
    {
        get
        {
             if (aGetter != null)
             {
                 return aGetter();
             }
        }
        set
        {
             if (aSetter != null)
             {
                 aSetter(value);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would essentially be pointing the getter of `ClassB` to the getter of `ClassA`, and likewise for the setters?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide an example of how to set a property's setter? I can easily obtain `ClassA`'s setter but can't figure out how to use this as `ClassB`'s setter.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Feels kinda hack-ey, but it does exactly what I was looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pub/sub system offered by MVVMLight (or similar) to send and receive notifications between classes and decouple direct dependencies between `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

Consider changing your classes like so.

```
public class ClassA
{
    private static IEnumerable<string> _whateverA;

    public static IEnumerable<string> WhateverA
    {
        get { return _whateverA; }
        set
        {
            _whateverA = value;
            // property changed, send message
            Messenger.Default.Send(new MyMessage(value));
        }
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB()
    {
        // receive message
        Messenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, message => 
        {
            WhateverB = message.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", WhateverB));
        });
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> WhateverB { get; set; }
}
```

Now whenever `ClassA` property changes, it'll notify `ClassB` to change it's property value accordingly. If instance does not exist, it doesn't crash your code at runtime, either.

Above `MyMessage` is simple class to help passing data around. You decide what this class should look like (hold all of ClassA instance?).

```
public class MyMessage : MessageBase
{
    public MyMessage(IEnumerable<string> value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Value { get; private set; } 
}
```

Now, if you have a super nice program

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var b = new ClassB();

        ClassA.WhateverA = new List<string> { "this", "is", "whatever" };
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It'll spit to Console

[image: example]

---

You'll need to install MVVMLight libraries via NuGet to get going.

> PM> Install-Package MvvmLightLibs -Version 5.2.0